# Instantiate COM out-of-process server object as logged on user from NetworkService

Tags: c#, .net, com, pinvoke, remote-assistance

I'm trying to use the [IRASrv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc240176.aspx) COM interface from my Windows service which runs as NetworkService. 
When I instantiate the `IRASrv` interface from a console app running as the logged-on user, everything works fine:

```
IRASrv srv = null;
try
{
    srv = (IRASrv)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(raSrvCLSID, true));
    if (srv != null)
    {
        Array sessionUsers = null;
        int sessionCount = 0;
        srv.GetSessionInfo(ref sessionUsers, ref sessionCount);
        if (sessionCount > 0)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            srv.GetNoviceUserInfo(ref result);
            Console.Out.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
catch (COMException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
finally
{
    if (srv != null)
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(srv);
    }
}
```

When I try the same code from my NetworkService service, `IRASrv` object instantiation fails with an Access Denied error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {3C3A70A7-A468-49B9-8ADA-28E11FCCAD5D} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

Next I tried impersonating the logged on user by using successive calls to:

- LogonUser(..., LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ...)
- WindowsImpersonationContext.Impersonate()

Impersonation succeeds but I still get the Access Denied error when I subsequently attempt to instantiate the COM server object.

My understanding of COM interop in C# is somewhat flaky. What could be going wrong here?

**Update**

I see this error in event logs:

> The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID {3C3A70A7-A468-49B9-8ADA-28E11FCCAD5D} and APPID {F8FD03A6-DDD9-4C1B-84EE-58159476A0D7} to the user NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE SID (S-1-5-20) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

So apparently impersonating the logged-on interactive user is not sufficient to activate the COM server.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771689.aspx

Comment: There isn't "a" logged on user on Windows. Multiple users can be logged in (see e.g. Fast User Switching or Remote Desktop). If you need to do something within a users session, you need code running there - e.g. an app that launches when users log in and then connects to your service to receive instructions. You service will need to cope appropriately with multiple copies of the app running.